# To make input-output pin of sensor high from mcu is it better to give logic high from mcu or making the mcu-pin input with pull-up?

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, pullup

I drive [sht11](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/Sensirion_Humidity_SHT1x_Datasheet_V5.pdf) temperature-humidity sensor from mcu, the reference design from MikroElektronika uses the following:
To make sda pin high, the pin connected to sda (which is pull-up) is not given to logic 1 instead, it is made input to make sda high.

I used this and it worked, I ask is it better and why?

```
/***************************************************************
* Generates a transmission start
*       _____         ________
* DATA:      |_______|
*           ___     ___
* SCK : ___|   |___|   |______
***************************************************************/
void Transmission_Start() {
  SDA_Direction = 1;                     // define SDA as input
  SCL = 1;                               // SCL high
  Delay_1us();                           // 1us delay
  SDA_Direction = 0;                     // define SDA as output
  SDA = 0;                               // SDA low
  Delay_1us();                           // 1us delay
  SCL = 0;                               // SCL low
  Delay_1us();                           // 1us delay
  SCL = 1;                               // SCL high
  Delay_1us();                           // 1us delay
  SDA_Direction = 1;                     // define SDA as input
  Delay_1us();                           // 1us delay
  SCL = 0;                               // SCL low
}
```

Comment: On page 5 of the datasheet it says *"To avoid signal contention the microcontroller must only drive DATA low. An external pull-up resistor (e.g. 10kΩ) is required to pull the signal high"* - I guess it means that you don't want to have the possibility that your micro drives it high while the sensor drives it low, giving a direct short.

Comment: @RogerRowland suggest you make this an answer so the question does not remain unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page 5 of the datasheet it says *"To avoid signal contention the microcontroller must only drive DATA low. An external pull-up resistor (e.g. 10kΩ) is required to pull the signal high"* - I guess it means that you don't want to have the possibility that your micro drives it high while the sensor drives it low, giving a direct short.